# Is Jupyter serverextension loaded when using Jupyterhub

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I wrote a Jupyter servertextension. When I configured it use `jupyter serverextension enable --py my_module` and started Jupyter Notebook with `jupyter notebook`, the extension worked well. But when I configured it in the same way and then started Jupyter using `jupyterhub`, the serverextension would not be loaded. Is there anyone who knows well about jupyterhub configuring, please?

Comment: how do you have `jupyerhub` set up? what spawner are you using?

Comment: What do you mean of 'spawner' ? I mean I wrote a Jupyter Serverextension like this [link](http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending/handlers.html). And it works well when I used `jupyter notebook`. But how can I let this extension work when I use `jupyterhub-singleuser`? Are any configuration options to open?

Comment: By spawner, I meant the process by which JupyterHub generates new `jupyter` servers (https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/wiki/Spawners). Since you mention `jupyterhub-singleuser`, I'm going to presume you're using DockerSpawner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [DockerSpawner](https://github.com/jupyterhub/dockerspawner), that means your `Jupyterhub` server creates a new container for each user and installs the notebook from scratch in that container. This is why your extension doesn't run - your regular `notebook` server has the extension installed but the `notebook` servers in the Docker containers haven't had your extension installed since you're using the default `jupyterhub/singleuser` image.

You will have to create a custom Docker image that you `JupyterHub` server will use to create your `notebook` servers. Here is a simple example Dockerfile to show you the basics:

```
FROM jupyterhub/singleuser

USER root

COPY /path/to/YourExtension-1.0.tar.gz /home/jovyan/work
RUN pip install YourExtension-1.0.tar.gz
RUN jupyter serverextension enable --py your_extension --sys-prefix    
RUN rm YourExtension-1.0.tar.gz
```

Obviously replace the references to "your extension" with the relevant names. All we're doing here is inheriting from the `jupyterhub/singleuser` image and copying over and installing the extension. Then, in your `JupyterHub` config, specify your Docker image (after building your docker image by running `docker build`) in your `jupyterhub_config.py` file like so:

```
c.DockerSpawner.image = 'yourrespository/yourimage'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But it is quite complex to write a customized Dockerfile since my extension has both front-end and back-end. Are there any other convenient approaches ?

Comment: It's not that much effort, just requires you to write out the steps of your installation process. If you want to use Docker this is the only solution. I haven't tried it but there is [systemdspawner](https://github.com/jupyterhub/systemdspawner) which spawns processes locally but still provides user encapsulation, but I don't know if installing an extension system-wide corresponds to all notebooks having that extension. Worth a try though if you're able to switch from Docker.